# Remove duplicates from OLAP Drill in SSAS

Tags: action, ssas, mdx, olap, drillthrough

I am using Visual Studios BIDS to modify an existing OLAP cube.

In `SSMS`: There is an underlying fact table (FactTableMain) with a very fine grain that contains 10 different measures to track the status of an application (they act almost like a flag). The measures either have the individual's ID value or are `NULL`.

In `SSAS` Visual Studio `OLAP`:

1. There are 10 measure groups. Each measure group is based on a DSV named query that selects 1 of the FactTableMain measures where MeasureName `IS NOT NULL`.
2. A drill action for each measure group with only the PersonName and PersonID columns being returned.

The drills for each measure group:

1. shows duplicates (as not all fact table columns are return columns for the drill)
2. Do not return the expected number of rows that the measure count displays

I have tried:

1. multiple `MDX` conditions using filter and distinct on the drill through action, but they either make no difference or the action disappears entirely
2. Create a junk drill dimension that selects the distinct IDs from the FactTableMain and set that as the only return column for the drill through action (made no difference to drill through return rows)
3. Creating New (Standard) Action as a rowset and dataset, using `MDX` action expressions

I think I need a New (Standard) Action with an `MDX` Action expression with these properties:

- Target type = Cells
- Target object = All cells
- Actions Content Type = Rowset

My current MDX query does return results, but only for the first measure's overall total and it is not formatted correctly at all. It does not work if I select a different measure in the client application, rerun the query, and drill again. I have searched and searched, but I am out of ideas and sitting in a black pit of doom. :(

My current `MDX` query is:

```
WITH 
  SET [person] AS 
    NonEmpty([person].[person].[person]) 
  MEMBER CurrentMeasure AS 
    [Measures].CurrentMember 
SELECT 
  NonEmpty
  (
    Filter
    (
      [Quarter].[Quarter].[Quarter].MEMBERS
     ,[Quarter].[Quarter].CurrentMember
    )
  ) ON COLUMNS
 ,(
    [person]
   ,NonEmpty([person].[person ID].[ID])
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Applications];
```

Goal:
I would ultimately like the drill action to be dynamic enough to know the current measure the user is selecting and filtered by the user's dimension selection for rows/columns.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to filter distinct or non empty rows using a condition for the original drill through action? I know there are drill limitations, but is there something that would workaround the drill's limitations?

   2. How can I create a Standard Rowset action that is dynamically to the user's selections (my goal).
   3. Any ideas?

A URL action type is not an option for our business needs.

EDIT: I removed everything unnecessary from the DSV and am selecting only distinct rows. Each ID can have more than 1 application and an application can have more than 1 area of interest. Now the drills return 1 row per ID, application, and area of interest. We only want the drill to return the distinct IDs, no matter the number of applications or areas of interest. I am not sure where to go from here. Can I filter our the application number and/or areas of interest dimensions in the drill?

Comment: This seems to me as too vague to understand, may be if you can restructure it and make more understandable. as @Hila suggested there may be some problem between linkage of your dimensions.

Comment: Hi Niraj, I tried to be as clear as possible. After fixing the DSV as @Hila suggested, I have been able to remove many of the duplicates. Please see my comment there.

Comment: Hi @SacredPanda if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are going too fast too quick.
The DSV should show the data without duplication in the browser. If it's not, go back to the DSV and check what it is. Maybe create a view (an Indexed view) on top of the fact table, so you can make sure that you query only the data that you want. Also: are you sure that your dimensions are linked correctly? Sometimes duplication appears  due to dimensions not being set up correctly with wrong keys for linkage.

In MDX:
If you create a Calculation in the Calculation tab you can do drill in it. Otherwise, you'll have to write the correct MDX query each and every time.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed unnecessary columns and added select DISTINCT to the DSV. The DSV rows are unique now. This greatly reduced the number of duplicates in the drill!
All the dimensions are link to the correctly. 
One ID can have multiple apps AND one app can have multiple "areas of interest". The table has 1 row per person, quarter, app, location, branch, and area of interest (distinct row, duplicate ID count). Users want to see the duplicates counts. However, the drill should only return the distinct ID, no matter how many applications or areas of interest.

Answer (score 0):

See the very last example at:
http://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Drillthrough&referringTitle=Home

You have to deploy that ASSP assembly to SSAS. It is used to pickup the current context on all attributes during execution of the action. But it will return totals by employee for whatever measure the user launched the action from.

```
"select {[Measures].CurrentMember} on 0, NON EMPTY [person].[person].[person].Members on 1 from (select (" + ASSP.CurrentCellAttributes([Measures].CurrentMember) + ") on 0 from [Application])"
```